# deploying jsf jpa web application in weblogic 12.1.1

Tags: spring, jsf, jpa, weblogic, weblogic12c

i am developping a web application using Maven , JSF 2.2 ,JSTL 1.2.1 , JPA 2.1 , Spring 4.2.9, Hibernate-jpa-api-2.1
i can deploy my application in Tomcat and run it without problems , but i want deploy in weblogic 12.1.1 as well but i got some problems starting my app server :

> nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError : javax.persistance.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;
>   ....
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException : Error creatin bean with name 'myEmf' defined in class path resource [jpaConfig.xml]
>   ....
>   Error javax.entreprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application

i have created a weblogic.xml in my deployed war like this :

```html
<prefer-application-packages> 
   <package-name>javax.faces.*</package-name> 
   <package-name>com.sun.faces.*</package-name> 
   <package-name>com.bea.faces.*</package-name> 
   </prefer-application-packages> 
 
   <prefer-application-resources> 
   <resource-name>javax.faces.*</resource-name> 
   <resource-name>com.sun.faces.*</resource-name> 
   <resource-name>com.bea.faces.*</resource-name> 
 
<resource-name>META-INF/services/javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer</resource-name>
</prefer-application-resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError" indicates a library collision with the JPA 2.0 Library of Weblogic. Since you are packing your own library for that, try adding "javax.persistence.*" to the weblogic.xml

---

Option 2: Add the JPA 2.1 Support to weblogic classpath

In your domain/bin/setDomainEnv (.cmd for windows, .sh for unix) add a PRE_CLASSPATH Variable. On a windows System this would look like this:

```
set PRE_CLASSPATH=C:/weblogic_12130/oracle_common/modules/javax.‌​persistence_2.1.jar;‌​C:/weblogic_12130/wl‌​server/modules/com.o‌​racle.weblogic.jpa21‌​support_1.0.0.0_2-1.‌​jar
```

Comment: You mean "javax.persistence.*" , i already tried it but i still got the same error

Comment: Okay, the other option requires a bit more work. You can try adding JPA 2.1 support to the weblogic classpath (it is an optional feature). In your domain/bin/setDomainEnv.cmd  set a "PRE_CLASSPATH"  variable to add JPA 2.1 Support. On a windows Installation this looks like this "set PRE_CLASSPATH=C:/weblogic_12130/oracle_common/modules/javax.persistence_2.1.jar;C:/weblogic_12130/wlserver/modules/com.oracle.weblogic.jpa21support_1.0.0.0_2-1.jar". I'll edit it in above